# Receive notifications when one's own questions are linked to in another post?

Tags: discussion, notifications

Often in a question, answer, or comment, someone will post a link to another existing related superuser question.

For now let us refer only to the posts where this is done because the posts are related, not because the new post is a duplicate of the existing one.

Are there any mechanisms that allow one to be notified if one's own questions are linked to in other posts?

Taking it to the next level, would it be appropriate to award reputation when this occurs? No?

Should either of these be a feature? Opinions?

Comment: No / No / Probably not: Notifications will probably be pretty annoying once you've contributed for a while (the 'nice answer' badge notifications become annoying as well after a while), and this feature could probably be abused; rep will be awarded regularly through additional readers that are directed to your posts.

Comment: Good point about the loophole for abuse, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: Not sure about notifications (that could get old, fast), but it would be nice to have a list of questions linking to the one you're viewing, e.g. on the sidebar (there's currently already a `Linked` section for questions the one you're viewing is linking *to*).

Comment: @Bob Getting a list is *maybe* possible with data.stackexchange.com. But I haven't had the time to check this

Comment: @nixda Well, a naive search is [easy enough](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/235700/posts-linking-to-post) when just testing if the post body contains the text. But it might be more useful as part of the `Related` column.

Comment: @Bob It looks like the feature you recommended has been added (I think last year sometime?) across the board to stack exchange sites! Fantastic!

Comment: @dtmland Hm. I've not noticed.